# Can I use the Netwon-Raphson method to solve a function that is a quadrature approximation of an arc-length integral?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson, arc-length, quadrature

I am using an arc length integral $\int_{t_0}^x \sqrt{(|ds|^2)} dt$ to solve for the $x$ that would give me a specific arc length. Assume that I know $t_0$, etc. and the only unknown is $x$. That is, I am solving for $x$ in

$$\int_{t_0}^x dt \sqrt{(|ds|^2)} = k$$

The particular integrand I am using doesn't seem to have a closed-form solution. So, I would like to approximate it using a quadrature rule (in this case, a 5-point Gauss-Legendre quadrature). That gives me an algebraic expression of the form

$$ k \approx \frac{x-t_0}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \sqrt{f(\xi_i\frac{x-t_0}{2}+\frac{t_0+x}{2})} $$

It is not immediately apparent how I would analytically solve for $x$, so instead I would like to use a root-finding algorithm such as the Newton-Raphson method.

My questions are:

1. Does this approach even make sense?
2. With the Newton-Raphson method, applying a difference of $\frac{f(x)}{f^{'}(x)}$ -  what does it even mean to take the derivative of an approximation of an integral? Does that matter here?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. The derivative of a primitive of $f$ is $f$ (with some assumptions on $f$). Additionally, it may be interesting to only compute the integral on $(x_n, x_{n+1})$, where $x_n$ are successive approximations of the solution. To get more accuracy, you may also use a composite quadrature method (divide the interval, use Gauss-Legendre on each subinterval), or use some sort of error control, etc. (the usual tricks with numerical quadrature)

Answer (score 1):

Let us make the problem more general.

You need to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\int_{t_0}^x g(t)\, dt-k$$ and you do not have the antiderivative of $g(t)$; so the integral will be computed by some numerical method of your choice.
Knowing a guess $x_0$ of the solution you will generate the first iterate using
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$ Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, this gives for Newton iterates
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}=x_n-\frac{\int_{t_0}^{x_n} g(t)\, dt-k}{g(x_n)}$$ and, at each step, you will compute $\int_{t_0}^{x_n} g(t)\, dt$.

For illustration purposes, let us consider $g(t)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{t}}}{t^{\pi }+1}$, $t_0=e$ and $k=4.567$ and we shall use $x_0=150$.

This will give as successive iterates
$$\{150.000,233.345,208.362,199.954,199.18,199.174\}$$

You could even use higher order methods such as Halley or Householder to reduce the number of required interations.

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful!